# Proof the sequence converges - contractive sequence, solution check

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Suppose we have a recursive sequence $a_n$ with $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=1+1/a_n$. Prove that $a_n$ is convergent and determine the limit of the sequence.

So far I have:

First $(a_n)>0,\forall n\in\Bbb N$. For $n>1$, we have $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{a_n}$ and $a_n=1+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$.

Note $\max(a_{n+1})=2$. Because $a_2=1+1=2$ and $a_3=1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$, $a_4=1+\frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{5}{3}$ $a_5=1+\frac{1}{\frac{5}{3}}=\frac{8}{5}$.....

So $\frac{3}{2}\le a_{n+1}-a_n \le 2$, thus,

$$\frac{3}{2}\le a_{n+1}-a_n = \left\lvert\frac{a_{n-1}-a_n}{a_na_{n-1}}\right\rvert\le 2$$ Since $a_n>\frac{3}{2}$

$$ a_{n+1}-a_n= \left\lvert\frac{a_{n-1}-a_n}{a_na_{n-1}}\right\rvert\le2\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2|a_{n-1}-a_n|=\frac{8}{9}|a_{n-1}-a_n|$$

So this is a Cauchy sequence.

Is this correct?

Comment: Right after you write "Note" on thee second line you make a false limit statement.

Comment: Wrong index, sry, hbn?

Comment: Now it is different, and I don't get how it follows from what you have before. Could you add to your post a proof of that limmit statement? Thanx.

Comment: In fact the limit (without the factor $a_{n+1}$) is exactly $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ so the statement is definitely incorrect. [if it were true $a_{n+1}$ would be constant.]

Comment: @coffeemath oh sry i meant the maximum.....sry. just corrected it, i took the max for the inequality that follows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131030/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-jerry-cohen).